# ToDo lists, tasks, and notes for Mac OS X and iOS

Tags: osx, ios, project-management

I am searching for an App (ideally for both Mac OS X and iOS), which combines a decent ToDo list and task manager with something like Apples notes application.

To add more background: I want to use it to keep track of scientific projects or projects in general, where the main focus is not to keep track the time frame (like a project management software does) but to document process and help organizing necessary next steps (and be able to check them off), adding meeting notes, tagging for better search, clear structuring (folders etc). It would be perfect if the Apple Pencil is supported so that I can add ideas and meeting notes directly by hand. Of course, I also want to add tables, format text, add files and figures etc.

Is there anything out there recommandable?

Comment: Online free "trello" should be tested ! https://trello.com

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) for the exact same purpose. Let's see what you need:

> - ideally for both Mac OS X and iOS

Available for both platforms. But you need the Plus version to access your mobile notes offline.

> - help organizing necessary next steps (and be able to check them off)

It has support for setting reminders in a To-Do-like list (with a checkbox next to each of them).

> - tagging for better search

Yes.

> - clear structuring (folders etc)

You can have multiple notebooks, if that is what you mean.

> - I also want to add tables, format text, add files and figures

There is support for basic formatting (including tables) and I have successfully managed to attach PDFs and pictures.

You can also add handwritten notes using the mobile version, or initiate a work chat (I've never used any of these).

P.S.: I have been using the premium plan, but most of the features are available for the free version as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Todoist](http://todoist.com). They have an iOS app, Mac app and companion website.

In order to add notes and assign due dates to tasks (Calendar integration), you will need to pay for the premium account.